# How to get abs() of an mpz in GMPY2?

Tags: python-3.x, gmpy

I need to get the absolute value of an `mpz` object in `GMPY2` but I cannot find any function like `abs()`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mpz objects provide `__abs__`, and so the ordinary `abs` works:

```
>>> gmpy2.mpz(3)
mpz(3)
>>> abs(gmpy2.mpz(3))
mpz(3)
>>> gmpy2.mpz(-3)
mpz(-3)
>>> abs(gmpy2.mpz(-3))
mpz(3)
```